# SQL Server global settings to get char field trimmed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

By default, MySQL returns char field after right trimming spaces from the string. 
However this is not the behavior expected by the ANSII standard. On the other hand, SQL Server, returns the spaces as is (as expected by the standard).

In MySQL, to change it we can set the variable sql_mode to include PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH in one of the following ways:

for the current session only:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH'
```

or globally:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH'
```

The question is: Does SQL Server has any equivalent setting that change the behavior so it will right trim spaces from  any char type (although it is not the ANSII standard) - so it will behave like MySQL?

Comment: Take a look into CHAR vs VARCHAR.  CHAR will have trailing spaces  Select Len5 = convert(char(5),'aaa'),Len3=convert(varchar(5),'aaa')

Comment: Thanks. I know the difference between these types. 
I am asking about globally change the retrieval behavior of char(n) fields in SQL Server so it will imitate the behavior of My SQL.

Comment: No that isn't you can do in sql server. I would make the case that you wouldn't want to anyway because that is actually changing the data when you retrieve it which could lead to some issues.

Comment: Not globally, as in the example provided, you would have to convert

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, SQL Server does has sql mode...

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/sql-modes-mysqltosql?view=sql-server-ver15

and equivalent to PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH is ANSI_PADDING try

```
SET ANSI_PADDING { ON | OFF }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This isn't the same thing. This is not at the session level it is at the server level. And this affects how the data is stored, not how it is retrieved. This actually strips the trailing spaces before storing it in the database.